# Localhost page keep returning message :This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect

Tags: docker

I am using docker on Mac pro.

the localhost page keeps returning the below  message when i do a docker-compose up -d:

```
This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

The localhost used to work, but then stopped working. Not sure what I did wrong.

```
version: '2'
services:
  apache:
    image: rafaelcgstz/magento2
    # build: .
    ports:
      - "80:80" # web
      - "9001:9000" # xdebug
      # - "35729:35729" # live reload
    volumes:
      - cleanMagento-sync:/var/www/html:nocopy
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer
      - ~/.npm:/var/www/.npm
      # - ~/.nvm:/var/www/.nvm
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=10.254.254.254 remote_connect_back=0"      
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=Docker"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    networks:
      - cleanMagento-network
networks:
  cleanMagento-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  cleanMagento-sync:
    external: true
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

any ideas on how to debug the issue will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

- i did some tests and now believe its to do with the apache

i did a

> ping 127.0.0.1

this returned :

```
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
```

i also checked if anyting else was listing on port:

> sudo lsof -i :80 | egrep "PID|LISTEN"

this returned ;

```
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   860 root    4u  IPv6 0xa09c168da64892ef      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   864 _www    4u  IPv6 0xa09c168da64892ef      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

i then tested my localhost;

> telnet localhost 80

this returned;

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
```

FINALLY i did a apache config test;

> apachectl configtest

this returned the following ERROR;

```
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for jon-MacBook-Pro.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

NOT clear if this is the cause of the problem, if so, how to fix it

Comment: We do need more information on your docker configuration. Please share a screenshot or additional configuration files.

Comment: hi @howdytom - i just added more information. i was just doing that when you gave me the minus score

Comment: There no downvotes on this question so accusing someone of doing that is considered poor form on this site.  Please see [ask] for tips on asking questions here.  Including all relevant info on your question can help avoid downvotes and closed questions.

Comment: @fsb i am so sorry guys. i did not mean to accuse anyone of anything. i am just a little stressed to find root of problem. i hope you can both forgive me. regards paul